# Error while running "waitForElementVisible" command for Microsoft Edge on nightwatchj.s

Tags: microsoft-edge, nightwatch.js

When I trying run test in Microsoft edge
browser starting and page is loading, but then I got error :

**TypeError: Error while running "waitForElementVisible" command: Error while trying to create HTTP request for "/wd/hub/session/8bf67432a94d18e24f88493fd249c629/element/[object Object]/displayed": Request path contains unescaped characters**

For Chrome and Firefox test works fine
Test code

```
 module.exports = {
      'Demo test Ecosia.org': function (browser) {
        browser
          .url('https://www.ecosia.org/')
          .waitForElementVisible('body')
          .assert.titleContains('Ecosia')
          .assert.visible('input[type=search]')
          .setValue('input[type=search]', 'nightwatch')
          .assert.visible('button[type=submit]')
          .click('button[type=submit]')
          .assert.containsText('.mainline-results', 'Nightwatch.js')
          .end();
      }
    };
```

My nightwatch.conf.js

```
const seleniumServer = require('selenium-server');
const edgeDriver = require('edgedriver');
const chromeDriver = require('chromedriver');
const geckoDriver = require('geckodriver');

module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['tests'],
  custom_commands_path: '',
  custom_assertions_path: '',
  page_objects_path: '',
  globals_path: '',
  live_output: false,
  disable_colors: false,
  parallel_process_delay: 10,
  "test_workers": {
    "enabled": false,
    "workers": "auto"
  },
  selenium: {
    start_process: true,
    //start_session: false,
    server_path:  seleniumServer.path, 
    check_process_delay: 5000,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4144,
    cli_args: {
      "webdriver.ie.driver": ieDriver.path,
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": chromeDriver.path,
      "webdriver.gecko.driver": geckoDriver.path,
      "webdriver.edge.driver":  "node_modules/edgedriver_win64/msedgedriver.exe"
    }
  },
  
  test_settings: {
    skip_testcases_on_fail: false,
    end_session_on_fail: false,
    default: {     
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
      }
    },
    
    chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        chromeOptions: {
          w3c: false,
          args: ['disable-gpu']
        }
      }
    },

    firefox: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        marionette: true,
            
      }
    },

    edge: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true
        
        
      }
    },
    
  }
};
```

Comment: Which version of Edge and operating system are you using? It seems that Nightwatch.js only supports Edge Legacy. If you're using Edge Chromium, you could refer to [this thread](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/2307) for the workaround but the workaround only works on Windows system.

Comment: windows 7 , Edge  83.0.478.58, thanks for links,the problem of the thread is that the browser is not supported and does not start. my browser starts, but does not execute  "waitForElementVisible" and etc commands

Comment: As you're using the new Edge which is based on chromium, I think you can refer to the same setting of Chrome. The same error occurs when using Chrome can be fixed by adding `"w3c": false`. The related thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378995/typeerror-err-unescaped-characters-on-testing-vue-project-using-nightwatch). You could also try the same solution in Edge Chromium.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.
 `edgeOptions:{
          w3c: false,
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using the new Edge which is based on chromium, I think you can refer to the same setting of Chrome.

The same error occurs when using Chrome can be fixed by adding `"w3c": false`. So you could add the following line to fix issue in Edge Chromium:

```
edgeOptions: { "w3c": false }
```

Reference link: [TypeError ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS on testing Vue project using Nightwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378995/typeerror-err-unescaped-characters-on-testing-vue-project-using-nightwatch)